# Is it a known property of the conics?

Tags: geometry

$(FP,FQ) $ are  focal radii of a hyperbola of major diameter $ 2a$ with $(P,Q) $ points  on  *either* branch such that $ FP−FQ=2a. $ Show that they make the same angle to that branch.

EDIT1:

changed to *either* branch

Posting as self answered. The figure hopefully  makes it clear using hyperbolic mirror property.

[image: Hyperbola Property]

Comment: Do you mean that in $|FP|-|F_1P|=2a$, $\angle FPF_1$ has the bisector which is tangent line at $P$ ?

Comment: Guess no error in the problem as given.

Comment: An illustration would be nice here.

Comment: Care to post the same diagram for ellipse?

Comment: It is well-known and very old. In the book Through The Mathescope by Ogilvie (Ogilvy?)  it shows  very nice 3-D constructions by Dandelin (circa 1830) that show the properties  $PF_1+PF_2=$constant for an ellipse, and $|PF_1-PF_2|=$constant for hyperbola. I have a plexiglass model of the Dandelin design for an ellipse, and found that it can be used to easily show the "equal angle" property, and I suspect that Dandelin's hyperbola design would do that also

Comment: I got the doubt when the segments are not meeting on the curve but emanate from a focus and seen  from a originating  equation (not given in the question but  described). It was difficult to immediately imagine the construction  to relate it to the well known property. Although not ingenious, without the construction it appeared to me  that the property  was not known.